Use date filter to filter between fromDate and toDate columns in power bi but also keep relationship
I have a Date Table named 'MyCalender'. I give the user the option to pick one date.

I also have two tables, one is 'Riskprofiler' and the other is 'RiskProfiler Comp'
Both cant have a relationship with the date table. So it looks like this.

I need to filter both tables when the user picks a date. I know this can be done using measures. I have created the measures that successfully does this.
The problem I have is that I also need to create a column based on the picked date. The column should is based on FSUM EUR.
The new column Fsum_EUR2 should be the SUM of Fsum_EUR but for just the picked date so I can for everyObj, so i CAN connect it to the following last table.

Both tables need the new FSUM_EUR2 column and be connected to the above table. Im having big problems solving this in POWER BI. Cant understand why they makes something this easy so hard to solve in PBI.
HERE IS A PICTURE OF HOW The Interval calculations will be.

For an example the count looks like this:
count #Vessels #RD = 
VAR _selectedDate = SELECTEDVALUE( myCalendar[Date] )

RETURN
CALCULATE( DISTINCTCOUNT( RiskProfil[OBJNUM] ) ,
(((RiskProfil[InsuranceStartDate] <= _selectedDate && RiskProfil[InsuranceEndDate] >= _selectedDate && ISBLANK( RiskProfil[STANND] ) ) 
|| ((RiskProfil[InsuranceStartDate] <= _selectedDate && RiskProfil[STANND] > _selectedDate) && NOT(ISBLANK(RiskProfil[STANND])) ))) 
) 

The Stannd column is just an annumlment Column
Ta add more info Fsum EUR2 looks like this:
FSUM EUR2 #RD = 
VAR _selectedDate = [Report Date]


RETURN
CALCULATE( SUM( RiskProfil[FSUM_EUR] ) ,
ALL(RiskProfil),
RiskProfil[OBJNUM] = SELECTEDVALUE(RiskProfil[OBJNUM]),
( RiskProfil[InsuranceStartDate] <= _selectedDate && RiskProfil[InsuranceEndDate] >= _selectedDate && ISBLANK(RiskProfil[STANND]) ) ||
( RiskProfil[InsuranceStartDate] <= _selectedDate && RiskProfil[STANND] > _selectedDate && NOT(ISBLANK(RiskProfil[STANND])) )
)


It looks like RiskProfil and RiskProfil Comparison have the same table structure. Have you considered combining RiskProfil and RiskProfil Comparison into a single table by introducing an additional column using constants to distinguish between the two row types, instead of having two tables?
Assuming you are retrieving the data from a SQL database you can use the advanced option to specify a custom a query or create a database view with a union and import data from the view instead.
something like this:
SELECT 
    AAFAR, 
    ANTHAVERI, 
    ..., 
    'RiskProfil' AS record_type 
FROM 
    Table1
UNION ALL 
SELECT 
    AAFAR, 
    ANTHAVERI, 
    ..., 
    'RiskProfil Comp' AS record_type 
FROM 
    Table2;


Yes I just did that the data is the same I just thought I need two tables since im filtering them based on 2023-08-30 and the same date on year earlier: 2022-08-30.
But it turns out I didnt need that.
But I still have problem with creating the FSUM_EUR2.
Which is calculated for each differently because of the different dates right.
I need to join them category for FSUM_EUR2. Is this also possible in a measure using switch.

So do you have something like this? FSUM_EUR2 = CALCULATE( SUM('RiskProfil'[FSUM_EUR]), 'RiskProfil'[Date] = EDATE(SELECTEDVALUE('myCalendar'[Date]), -12) )

I Have this one.
FSUM EUR2 #CD =
VAR _selectedDate = [Comparison Date]
RETURN
CALCULATE( SUM( RiskProfil[FSUM_EUR] ) ,
ALL(RiskProfil),
RiskProfil[OBJNUM] = SELECTEDVALUE(RiskProfil[OBJNUM]),
( RiskProfil[InsuranceStartDate] <= _selectedDate && RiskProfil[InsuranceEndDate] >= _selectedDate && ISBLANK(RiskProfil[STANND]) ) ||
( RiskProfil[InsuranceStartDate] <= _selectedDate && RiskProfil[STANND] > _selectedDate && NOT(ISBLANK(RiskProfil[STANND])) )
)
AND #CD stands for Comparison Date
I Have the same but for #RD ReportDate

I just switch between
Comparison Date = SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR( myCalendar[Date] )
Report Date = SELECTEDVALUE( myCalendar[Date] )
The measure is fine.
But then i need to count how many inside a specific interval. How many premiums within a specific intervall I will add i picture

Maybe I should run a direct Query and calculate FSUM_EUR2 inside SQL and then join them into my table using OBJNUM.

I solved this one using a direct Quary instead of import quary but only for FSUM EUR2 to get a connection for everytime a user changes date
